# Promising gets stuck when doing actions on the data

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a problem with promises. I have to do two queries to the database and I have to use `then` to read them. After that I have to merge them. What I did is as follows:

```
console.log("Start");
obj.find(query1).then(function(docs1) {
    console.log("HERE0");
    obj.find(query2).then(function(docs2) {
        // Merge reports
        console.log("HERE1");
        console.log("docs1");
        console.log("docs2");
        c = [...docs1.files, ...docs2.files];
        console.log("HERE2");
        for (let i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            for (let j = i + 1; j < c.length; j++) {
                console.log("i = " + i + " j = " + j);
                if(c[i].name == c[j].name) {
                    c[i].totals.invalid += c[j].totals.invalid ;
                    c[i].totals.valid += c[j].totals.valid ;
                    c[i].totals.total += c[j].totals.total;
                    c[i].totals.percentage = (c[i].totals.invalid / c[i].totals.valid) * 100;
                    c.splice(j, 1)
                }
            }
        }
        console.log("DONE");
        response.send(c);
    }, function (err) {
       logger.error(err.message);
       response.status(500).send(err.message);
    });
}, function (err) {
    logger.error(err.message);
    response.status(500).send(err.message);
});
```

Output:

```
Start
HERE0
HERE1
<valid docs1>
<valid docs2>
```

After he gets to the line `c = [...docs1.files, ...docs2.files];` it's get stuck (doesn't get to the next prints) and I don't understand why. I can see those docs being printed to the console.log but why it does not work on that line?

Also, is there a better way of of performing the `find` call so there will be one nesting instead of two (one `.then`)?

**EDIT**: the `find` method uses `Q.defer();`. Maybe I need to use it too?

Comment: Do you get an error? *"is there a better way of of performing the find call"* yes, but this doesn't fix your problem. *"Maybe I need to use it two?"* It's *"too"* ;) and no, you don't need to do that.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry for the typo :) I don't get an error, it just stuck on that line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.all` with `obj.find(query1)` and `obj.find(query2)` expressions and later use them in thenable callback.

As far as merging function is concerned I prefer to use `reduce` and `find` for this example

Take a look at the snippet with mocked values.

```js
const random = (from, to) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from) + from);

const randomObj = (id) => {
  const name = `sample ${id}`;
  const invalid = random(1, 6);
  const valid = random(6, 12);
  const percentage = invalid / valid * 100;

  return {
    name,
    totals: {
      invalid,
      valid,
      percentage
    }
  }
}

const obj = {
  find: (query) => Promise.resolve(Array(random(1, 4)).fill(0).map((pr, index) => randomObj(index + 1)))
}
const query1 = ""
const query2 = ""

Promise.all([obj.find(query1), obj.find(query2)]).then(results => {

  let [list, secondList] = results;

  console.log('first list', list);
  console.log('second list', secondList);

  const result = list.reduce((acc, record) => {

    const item = secondList.find(pr => pr.name === record.name);

    if (item) {
      record.totals.invalid += item.totals.invalid;
      record.totals.valid += item.totals.valid;
      record.totals.percentage = record.totals.invalid / record.totals.valid * 100;
    }

    acc = [...acc, record];

    return acc;
  }, [...secondList.filter(pr => !list.some(npr => npr.name === pr.name))])

  console.log('result', result);
})
```

Comment: Your optimization of the merge is premature. Do you know that the `name` is distinct within the input arrays? And what about the items in `secondList` that don't have a corresponding member in `list`?

Comment: Yeah, I realized it now. Quite silly of me. Going to fix that